# Python TypeError when import "mlab" module in Abaqus PDE

Tags: python, matlab, abaqus, python-mlab, mlab

Windows Machine, Python 2.7 64 bit, Abaqus 6.14

I tried to call matlab function in Python scripts var "mlab" module. It ran well in the Python IDEL. But when importing "mlab" in ABAQUS PDE, I got an *Python Error*. TypeError coercing to Unicode:need string or buffer, list found. and ABAQUS was broken done, "ipc_CONNECTION_BROKEN","UnException TypeError:"'NoneType' object is not callable" in ignored.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0soAT.png)

Comment: if you are using mlab only for post processing i'd suggest you export the data and write a separate stand-alone script to do the plotting.